# How to force time series in pivot chart -- force break in line

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a housing transaction dataset that looks like this:

```
geography | date | housing type | sq.ft. | sale price | price/sq.ft.
```

I can make a pivot chart showing the change in, say, `price/sq.ft.` over time, and filter that by one of the 20 geographies I have. Here's an example of what I can make below:

[image]

I've added two more fields (`saleyear` and `salequarter`) and calculated them based on the `date` field. The problem is that not all geographies had a transaction in each quarter. Instead of showing missing data (i.e., a break in the line), the x-axis shortens and throws off the pattern. You can see this in year 1999 in the image above.

**TL;DR:** How do I make the pivot chart show the date for a missing value and just show a break in the line?

Answer (score 3):

Pivot tables (and pivot charts) only show data that is present in the data source. If you want to make sure that all quarters are showing on the X axis, you must have all quarters present in the source data. They don't have to have values against them.

[image]

Use the "Select Data source > Hidden and Empty Cells" settings to control whether the gap is showing or closed by connecting the data points with a line.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. That answered my question! Unfortunately, I have to go through my rather extensive dataset by hand and manually add the dummy/missing quarters.

Comment: You don't need to do that. You can add the empty data values to the end of the source table. It only needs to be **somewhere** in the data source, not slotted in perfectly.

Comment: Aha, so I could just make a full dummy set of years/quarters with blanks and replicate it across all geographies--maybe not what you were getting at, but it would be easier than trying to find out where the missing year/quarters were for each geography.

Comment: yes, that's the idea.